# How do I determine the main verb in a sentence?

Tags: infinitives

I'm not a native speaker. How do I determine what the main verb is in a sentence like

> I used to hurt people.

Comment: See this question & answers from the English SE site: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55384/determining-main-verb-of-a-sentence-which-match-with-subject-verb-to-verb

Comment: How do you determine the main verb in your mother tongue? Tell us your procedure. Then follow it for this English sentence. What does it get you?

Comment: @ЯegDwight i mean should i take hurt as verb or to hurt  infinitive as verb??

Comment: @ЯegDwight It's the last word in the sentence in my language. So, is it the word *people*? ; -)

Comment: @ЯegDwight In our mother toungue also we determine the verb based on action.

Comment: @KaranamVishnuVardhan It kind of depends on what you mean by "main verb" ...

Comment: @Araucaria the one doing the action

Comment: See the [Verb Phrase Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), which explains that the last verb in a verb phrase is normally the main verb. _Used to_ is close enough to an auxiliary verb that it only refers to time, like perfect _have_; _I have hurt people_ has much the same assertion, but not the same presupposition, as the OQ.

Answer (score 8):

SHORT ANSWER:
In your example, *hurt* is the lexical verb, cast in the infinitive after the auxiliary *used*. *To* may be regarded as an infinitive marker on *hurt*, required by this particular auxiliary; but it is now tied so strongly to *used* that it may equally be regarded as a component of a new lexeme *useta*.

LONGER ANSWER:
The expression “main verb” does not (as far as I know) have a fixed meaning in the formal discussion of English grammar. It is not a technical descriptive term but one employed by teachers to draw learners toward understanding, and its meaning will vary from context to context.

So let’s replace your term “main verb” with what I suspect you’re talking about, which is the distinction between “auxiliary verb” and “lexical verb”. Over the centuries English has evolved a system of verb constructions in which the lexical (“dictionary”) verb, the one which expresses a particular eventuality, is preceded by one or more auxiliary (“helping”) verbs which express grammatical categories: tense, aspect, voice, mode. All of these auxiliary verbs were originally lexical verbs, and some of them (*have* and *be*, for instance) are still used in other contexts as lexical verbs. But in the context of the verb constructions they are fully “grammaticalized”: they express only grammatical meaning, not lexical meaning.

Note that in any verb construction of more than one verb there are two verbs which might be described as “main”.

- *Semantically*, it is always the **last** verb in the construction which is the lexical verb: it expresses the core meaning, action or state, and in this sense it is the “main”.
- In a construction, however, this verb is always cast in a “non-finite” form—a participle or infinitive.

  > He has **seen**<sup>PaPpl</sup>
  >   He is **seeing**<sup>PrPpl</sup>
  >   He will **see**<sup>Inf</sup>

  *Syntactically* it is the **first** verb in a construction which is the “head” of the verb phrase, and only this first verb can be “finite”—inflected for person, number and tense.

  > He **has**<sup>Finite</sup> seen
  >   I **am** <sup>Finite</sup> seeing
  >   I **will**<sup>Finite</sup> see

This fairly straightforward situation has recently gotten a little more complicated. In the longest-established verb constructions, any infinitive forms are “bare”—not accompanied by *to*. But in the last couple of centuries (the blink of an eye in linguistic terms), English has evolved a new set of auxiliary expressions—*have to* for *must*, and *be going to* for *will*, for instance—which take “marked infinitives”—infinitive forms preceded by the “infinitive marker” *to*. These expressions usually found their origin in *lexical* senses of their verbs:

> He **has** this task to do. → He has to do this task.
>   He **is going** there tomorrow to help them. → He is going to help them there tomorrow.

But in many cases the marker has become syntactically and phonetically very strongly bound to the preceding verb. With *Have to* = *must*, for instance, the *to* cannot be separated from the *have* form, and the pronunciation has changed from /hæv tə/ to /hæftə/—*hafta*. In these circumstances it is very difficult to decide whether the *to* “belongs” to the preceding auxiliary or to the following lexical verb.

*Used to* is a similar case. Originally the *use* in this expression was unambiguously a lexical verb meaning “do habitually, practice”, pronounced with /z/ and employed in all tenses:

> His own Wife would often say, you must not believe my husband; for he **uses** to tell Lies to make Gentlemen laugh. —[1719](https://books.google.com/books?id=igRcAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA76&dq=%22he+uses+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mfo0Vb2RDIHnggT8loDoBw&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22he%20uses%20to%22&f=false)

But today *use* has become fully grammaticalized in this sense. It is employed only in the past tense, and it has undergone the same phonetic reduction as *have to*, with devoicing of the final consonant, /justə/—*useta*. If you want to regard *useta* as a new auxiliary and *hurt* as a bare infinitive I won't argue with you!

Comment: Your English too strong, but is this understanding correct: In the past, *"used"* will be regarded as **main verb** but now *"hurt"* is regarded instead.

Comment: Exactly! In the past *I used to hurt people* had the same pattern as *I wanted to hurt people*, but now it has the same pattern as *I had to hurt people*.

Comment: +1 I'm just wondering about catenations such as "I want to go" ...

Comment: @Araucaria First snailboat and now you! I refuse to be drawn into making this long answer any longer. Ask a question (and then answer it, since you probably know more about catenae than I do).

Comment: @StoneyB I thought it was a great answer, I was just wondering what you thought.

Comment: @Araucaria I think *use (to)* is a catenating verb but *useta* is a typically defective modal (albeit with atypical defects).

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to find the main verb.

All you have to do is to find what is the sentence trying to convey you mainly and plays the biggest role.

> I used to hurt people.

The main verb is *hurt* because its main agenda is to tell you that you *hurt* people.

---

**e.g.**
*I love to play video games whenever I am free.*

*"love"* is the main verb since my agenda to tell you is what I love — play video games.

Another way to identify is to test if it can standalone *(not recommended)*,

**i.e.**
*I **love** video games.*

---

**e.g.**
*Many high school students, some of whom are aged 12 only, have a part-time job.*

The main verb is *"have"* since my agenda is to tell you many high school students have part-time jobs, others are extra.

many high school students → **have** a part-time job

So, it is fine to be standalone too.

**i.e.**
*Many high school students **have** a part-time job.*

Comment: can you give me some examples with "used to"

Comment: That's more easy. _I used to play computer games._ So, *"play"* is the **main verb**. *"used"* just kind of adverb only, doesn't make any sense with that verb alone since it's just describing the main verb (by frequency) but it makes sense with *"play"* alone. **i.e.** _I play computer games._

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say that the *tensed* or *finite* verb is the "main" verb in a sentence. Example time!

> She **writes**
>   She was going to have been **writing** the paper
>   She had **written** the paper.
>   She (could/would/might/may) **write** the paper tomorrow.

In English, the last verb in the verb phrase is the "main" verb. Things get a bit more difficult with subordinate clauses, but that's probably a separate question.

Comment: please check my other post related to same sentence. then you will understand my question better.

Comment: Do you really think "was going to have been writing" is a helpful example?

Comment: No, if there is more than one verb in a verb phrase the tensed verb will be the first auxiliary verb. If there is only one verb in a verb phrase, that's the main verb; but if there are more than one, the last verb in the verb phrase is normally the main verb. But that's only for the auxiliary verb chains up to _She must not have been being photographed all that time_, where the (untensed) modal _must_ is the first verb, but _photographed_ is the **main** verb. Main verbs determine other things, like possible particles, complements, alternation rules, deletions, etc.

Comment: @JohnLawler yes, you're right. Clearly I'm out of practice ;) Actually, are you familiar at all with functional grammar? I have a feeling that what I said is true in that paradigm, but don't have my books on hand.

Comment: @TRomano I suppose my example needs more explanation, but do you really think a comment like yours is constructive or helpful? ;)

Comment: @jimsug: Depends on which flavor of functional grammar you're referring to. That sounds like a revision of "head", which could be the first auxiliary verb in some theories; either way, what I'm talking about is the description of the verb phrase from the [Verb Phrase Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), which comes after the [Logic Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), but doesn't depend on it for much, except the ideas of clauses, predicates, and arguments.

Comment: @jimsug: actually, I wasn't trying to be constructive but destructive. Destructivism gets a bad rap.