# Will there be multiple main verbs in any sentences?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure, coordination

Short sentences like:

> She **is** a girl.
>   
> She **writes** composition.
>   
> She **will** be killed by him.
>   
> She **loves** to shop in the mall.

The **main verb**s are obvious.

But I am wondering will there be any cases that there are multiple main verbs? **If yes**, can you please give me examples too? *(they should strictly be sentences, not paragraphs.)*

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/55175/3281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sentence may have a [compound verb](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/sentences/15-sentences-using-compound-subjects-and-compound-verbs.html),

**e.g.**

> She **writes** well and **has won** a prize for composition.

One subject, two verbs.